# Getting the time from a Bootstrap Timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I'm trying to get the time from a [Bootstrap Timepicker](http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/) using the [getTime](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/blob/master/js/bootstrap-timepicker.js) function, but only get an error message in the console when I press the button (with ID of my-button, see code below.)

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
    <input type="text" class="timepicker input-small">
    <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-time"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#my-button').on('click', function() {
    alert($('.timepicker').getTime());
  });

  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
    template : 'dropdown',
    showInputs: false,
    showSeconds: false
  });
</script>
```

**Error in the console**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getTime'
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours. I thought I could use the source code to learn how to use the picker, and it looks like there's a getTime() function, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use it. I'm using Rails, for what it's worth. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a public function, the method getTime is private to just that function. Meaning you can't access it.

If you want to get the time just do a `.val();` and parse it. Or you could modify the script to expose `.getTime();` function.

Answer (score 13):

FWIW it is possible to call `getTime()` but it can't be called directly because `$('.timepicker')` returns the <input> element from the DOM, not the actual timepicker object.

It's not mentioned in the documentation, but if you look at the bootstrap-timepicker.js source then the binding function (`$.fn.timepicker`) stores a reference to the actual timepicker object against the DOM element, using jQuery's data() feature.

So, this works:

```
$('.timepicker').data("timepicker").getTime();
```

(Of course `getTime()` still just returns a string, so in this case the parent's suggestion of using val() is probably cleaner unless you think there might be invalid data typed into the field, and not yet cleaned by the timepicker.)

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#ReportingTime').data('timepicker').hour;

$('#ReportingTime').data('timepicker').minute;

$('#ReportingTime').data('timepicker').meridian;
```